# Pushed changes in staging area

Tags: git, github, gerrit

So I pushed some code to gerrit for review . Shortly after I did something along the lines of git reset --soft HEAD-1 now all the changes I pushed are showing back up in the staging area. Is there any way to undo this ?I ran the reset command by mistake dropped something on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting thing that you dropped and that hit the keys in that order exactly. :-D.

If you didn't do anything else, `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` should undo what you did. A `--soft` reset does nothing more than changing the branch pointer, leaving the index and worktree as they are. So if you just repoint the branch pointer where it belongs you are fine. You can verify with `git reflog` before you do the command, whehter `HEAD@{1}` is really what you want to reset to. Alternatively if you know the correct SHA, you can also reset to that directly.

Comment: 5d768a4e HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
5d768a4e HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
5d768a4e HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD^
48694552 HEAD@{3}: commit (amend):

this is the status of reflog i need to go back to directly after the commit(amend) a git reset --soft  HEAD@{3} should do the trick? So i need to be inbetween HEAD2 and HEAD 3

Comment: Changes suggested worked. 
Used git reflog to identify exactly where i needed to be.
Then used git reset --hard HEAD@{3} (where 3 is the index i identifed as last good commit.)
Also note reset hard will remove any uncommitted changes so use with caution